# Generate audiotrack as separate thread and make manipulations during playing

Tags: java, android, multithreading, audio, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to build an app in java with android studio, and what I want to do is to generate a AudioTrack (right now basically a sine wave), but I want this to run as a separate thread (so multiple tracks can be started simultaneous, and also the rest of the app is not locked while playing), and I want to make it stop on demand (for example pushing a stop button). However I also want to be able to make changes in parameters such as frequency while the track is playing and get these changes in more or less realtime (a small delay is definitely acceptable)

This must be pretty standard, but I can't get my head around how to do it, because if the class generating the audio is a separate class I seem to loose access to the built in functions (if they are not native to Thread class), and also I can't make changes to internal variables (like frequency), while the audio is being generated.

Below is the code right now producing the sound, basically building a buffer in a loop and then writing to the audio track. Any ideas how I can do this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < mSound.length; i++)  {
            double beatFreq = Math.sin((2.0*Math.PI * i/(44100/this.beat)));
            mSound[i] = beatFreq*Math.sin((2.0*Math.PI * i/(44100/this.pitch)));
            mBuffer[i] = (short) (mSound[i]*Short.MAX_VALUE);

        }

        mAudioTrack.setStereoVolume(AudioTrack.getMaxVolume(), AudioTrack.getMaxVolume());
        mAudioTrack.play();

        mAudioTrack.write(mBuffer, 0, mSound.length);
        mAudioTrack.stop();
        mAudioTrack.release();
```